# Elements in a CakePHP project

Tags: cakephp

I am new in CakePHP, trying to make a site in it. In the site, I have some elements which come several times(header, footer, bottom parts). In the "bottom" part, I have some images. Problem is, those images are showed on only "Home" page, not the other pages (about, contact, etc.) The "bottom" part is :
p

```
<div class="bottom">
.
.
.
<div class="col col14">
    <h4>Photo Gallery</h4>
    <ul class="footer_gallery">
       <li><a href="img/image_l.jpg"><img src="img/image_1.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a> </li>
       <li><a href="img/image_2.jpg"><img src="img/image_2.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_3.jpg"><img src="img/image_3.jpg" alt="Image 03" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_4.jpg"><img src="img/image_4.jpg" alt="Image 04" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_5.jpg"><img src="img/image_5.jpg" alt="Image 05" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_6.jpg"><img src="img/image_6.jpg" alt="Image 06" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_7.jpg"><img src="img/image_7.jpg" alt="Image 07" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_8.jpg"><img src="img/image_8.jpg" alt="Im'age 08" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="img/image_9.jpg"><img src="img/image_9.jpg" alt="Image 09" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
    <a href="portfolio.html" class="more">more</a>
</div>
.
.
.
</div>p
```

Comment: Add some code so that people can investigate your problem

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is a CakePHP related problem, but when using Cakephp, the best approach is to use Cake's HTML Helper as such:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image("image_1.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Image 1",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'examplecontroller', 'action' => 'view', 6)
)); ?>
```

However, if you still want to stick with what you have here, then you need to make sure your links to the image are represented as

`<li><a href="/img/image_l.jpg"><img src="/img/image_1.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a> </li>`

not `<li><a href="img/image_l.jpg"><img src="img/image_1.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a> </li>`

This way you are guaranteed to reach your image, regardless of where you are calling it from within your app.

Comment: I think it's a common problem to use relative urls for assets and wonder why the url `/foo/bar` leaves the page without images/css/js files. **Always use Helpers for assets and urls** is valid CakePHP-specific advice which prevents this.

Comment: Totally agree!!! CakePHP is beautiful for things like these! I am in love with CakePHP!

Comment: Yeah, I also want to use Cake's as much features as possible, but what'd be the "controller" and "action" here ? This is a simple image, I want my users will see just the image when they click on it (nothing else) . @A_Santiago

Comment: I just grabbed that from the cookbook, but I believe instead of the controller stuff, you could replace it with `'url' => $this->Html->image("image_1.jpg")`. I haven't tested it, but I think that would work just fine...